# Wrong Bookmark Depth

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, bookmarks

Consider the following non-MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  hmargin = 2.4cm,
  vmargin = 3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  pdftitle = {Teknologiens betydning for menneskers sundhed og levevilkår},
  pdfauthor = {Svend Mortensen},
  pdfsubject = {Fysik/kemi},
  pdfstartview = FitH,
  breaklinks,
  hidelinks
}

\renewcommand*\cftsecleader{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\clearpage
\addtocounter{page}{130}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {section}
  {\protect\numberline{1}Kommunikation -- Tekster}
\label{A-kommunikation-forside}
\includepdf[pages = 1]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.1}Kommunikationssystemer}
\label{A-1-kommunikationssystemer}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.1.1}Mobiltelefonen}
\label{A-11-mobiltelefonen}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.1.2}Digitalisering og binært sprog}
\label{A-12-digitalisering-binaert-sprog}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.2}Trådløs kommunikation}
\label{A-1-traadloes-kommunikation}
\includepdf[pages = 2]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.2.1}De første radiobølger}
\label{A-21-de-foerste-radioboelger}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.2.2}Marconi sender signal over Atlanterhavet}
\label{A-22-marconi-sender-signal-over-atlanterhavet}
\includepdf[pages = 3]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.2.3}Fjernsynet -- et nyt kommunikationssystem}
\label{A-23-fjernsynet–et-nyt-kommunikationssystem}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.2.4}Det startede i USA}
\label{A-24-det-startede-i-usa}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.2.5}Fjernsyn i Danmark}
\label{A-25-fjernsyn-i-danmark}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.2.5}Daglige udsendelser}
\label{A-26-daglige-udsendelser}
\includepdf[pages = 4]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.3}Lagring af information}
\label{A-3-lagring-af-information}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.3.1}Edisons fonograf}
\label{A-31-edisons-fonograf}
\includepdf[pages = 5]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.3.2}Grammofonpladen}
\label{A-32-grammofonpladen}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.3.3}Grammofonens tidsalder}
\label{A-33-grammofonens-tidsalder}
\includepdf[pages = 6]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.3.4}Magnetisk lagring af lyd}
\label{A-34-magnetisk-lagring-af-lyd}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.3.5}Båndoptageren}
\label{A-35-båaadoptageren}
\includepdf[pages = 7]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.3.6}Kassettebåndoptageren}
\label{A-36-kassettebaandoptageren}
\includepdf[pages = 8]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.3.7}Walkman}
\label{A-37-walkman}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.3.8}Compact disc}
\label{A-38-compact-disc}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.3.9}Cd'en afløses af MP3}
\label{A-39-cd'en-afloeses-af-mp3}
\includepdf[pages = 9]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}
\clearpage

\addtocounter{page}{-16}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsection}
  {\protect\numberline{1.4}Tip~10}
\label{A-4-tip-10}
\includepdf[pages = -]{1-tip-ti-kommunikation.pdf}
\clearpage

\addtocounter{page}{16}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {section}
  {\protect\numberline{2}Den digitale revolution -- Tekster}
\label{B-den-digitale-revolution-forside}
\includepdf[pages = 10]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.1}De første computere}
\label{B-1-de-foerste-computere}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.1.1}Computeren Colossus}
\label{B-11-computeren-colossus}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.1.2}Koden brydes}
\label{B-12-koden-brydes}
\includepdf[pages = 11]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.1.3}Tyskerne vidste ikke, at koden var brudt}
\label{B-13-tyskerne-vidste-ikke-at-koden-var-brudt}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.1.4}ENIAC}
\label{B-14-eniac}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.1.5}Computerne bliver mindre}
\label{B-15-computerne-bliver-mindre}
\includepdf[pages = 12]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.2}Udvikling af computerens hjerne}
\label{B-2-udvikling-af-computerens-hjerne}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.2.1}Elektronrøret}
\label{B-21-elektronroeret}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.2.2}Computere anvender det binære talsystem}
\label{B-22-computere-anvender-det-binaere-talsystem}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.2.3}Elektronrøret som forstærker}
\label{B-23-elektronroeret-som-forstaerker}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.2.4}Transistoren afløser elektronrøret}
\label{B-24-transistoren-afloeser-elektronroeret}
\includepdf[pages = 13]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.2.5}Transistorer i computere}
\label{B-25-transistorer-i-computere}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.2.6}Mikrochippen}
\label{B-26-mikrochippen}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.2.7}Lommeregnere}
\label{B-27-lommeregnere}
\includepdf[pages = 14]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.3}Den personlige computer}
\label{B-3-den-personlige-computer}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.3.1}Apple}
\label{B-31-apple}
\includepdf[pages = 15]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.3.2}Computere til hjemmebrug bliver billigere}
\label{B-32-computere-til-hjemmebrug-bliver-billigere}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.3.3}Bærbare pc'er}
\label{B-33-baerbare-pcer}
\includepdf[pages = 16]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.3.4}Håndholdte computere}
\label{B-34-håaadholdte-computere}
\includepdf[pages = 17]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.4}Internettet}
\label{B-4-internettet}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.4.1}2~milliarder brugere}
\label{B-41-2-milliarder-brugere}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.4.2}WWW}
\label{B-42-www}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.4.3}Kobberkabler, lyslederkabler og båndbredde}
\label{B-43-kobberkabler-lyslederkabler-og-baandbredde}

\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.4.4}Alle computere på internettet har en adresse}
\label{B-44-alle-computere-paa-internettet-har-en-adresse}
\includepdf[pages = 18]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}
\clearpage

\addtocounter{page}{-19}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsection}
  {\protect\numberline{2.5}Tip~10}
\label{B-5-tip-10-den-digitale-revolution}
\includepdf[pages = -]{2-tip-ti-digital-revolution.pdf}
\clearpage

\addtocounter{page}{-19}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {section}
  {\protect\numberline{3}Elektriske komponenter -- Eksperimenter}
\label{C-elektriske-komponenter-forside}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsection}
  {\protect\numberline{3.1}Fumlebrættet og elektriske kompenenter}
\label{C-1-fumlebrarttet-og-elektriske-kompenenter}
\includepdf[pages = 19]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsection}
  {\protect\numberline{3.2}Lysdiode og elektrisk modstand}
\label{C-2-lysdiode-og-elektrisk-modstand}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{3.2.1}Hvordan virker en lysdiode og en elektrisk modstand? -- side~1}
\label{C-21a-hvordan-virker-en-lysdiode-og-en-elektrisk-modstand-s1}
\includepdf[pages = 20]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{3.2.1}Hvordan virker en lysdiode og en elektrisk modstand? -- side~2}
\label{C-21b-hvordan-virker-en-lysdiode-og-en-elektrisk-modstand-s2}
\includepdf[pages = 21]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsection}
  {\protect\numberline{3.3}Kondensator}
\label{C-3-kondensator}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{3.3.1}Brug af en kondensator -- side~1}
\label{C-31-brug-af-en-kondensator-s1}
\includepdf[pages = 22]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{3.3.2}Brug af en kondensator -- side~2}
\label{C-32-brug-af-en-kondensator-s2}
\includepdf[pages = 23]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsection}
  {\protect\numberline{3.4}Transistor -- modstand?}
\label{C-4-transistor-modstand}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{3.4.1}Transistoren som elektrisk modstand? -- side~1}
\label{C-41-transistoren-som-elektrisk-modstand-s1}
\includepdf[pages = 24]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{3.4.2}Transistoren som elektrisk modstand? -- side~2}
\label{C-42-transistoren-som-elektrisk-modstand-s1}
\includepdf[pages = 25]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}
\clearpage

\addtocounter{page}{6}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsection}
  {\protect\numberline{3.6}Transistor -- strømregulator}
\label{C-6-transistor-stroemregulator}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{3.6.1}Regulering af strømmen gennem en transistor -- side~1}
\label{C-61-regulering-af-stroem-gennem-en-transistor-s1}
\includepdf[pages = 27]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsubsection}
  {\protect\numberline{3.6.2}Regulering af strømmen gennem en transistor -- side~2}
\label{C-62-regulering-af-stroem-gennem-en-transistor-s2}
\includepdf[pages = 28]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline
  {toc}
  {subsection}
  {\protect\numberline{3.7}Regulering af en transistor med en lys-sensor}
\label{C-7-regulering-af-en-transistor-med-en-lys-sensor}
\includepdf[pages = 29]{teknologiens-betydning-kompendium.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image: ToC]

**Question**

As can be seen in the screenshot, the bookmark depths don't follow the depth of the ToC entries. How do I fix the bookmark depths to align with the ToC entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need either `\phantomsection` everywhere (this could be a bug, I will look later), but probably the best is to simple load the [`bookmark`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) package:

`\usepackage{bookmark}`

[image]